# Correct syntax for the return of a program

Tags: linux, bash, shell

im a newbie in bash scripts. I'm trying to create a backup script and I need to check if a program run via a bash command.

My try :

```
echo -e "\e[36mCheck the return\e[0m"
if [ bash "$TSFOLDER"/ts3server_startscript.sh status == "Server is running"]; then
echo -e "\e[32m    ► Server is running\e[0m"
exit
else    
echo -e "\e[31m    ► Server is not running\e[0m"
fi
```

Thanks you

Comment: The general rule is scripts/utilities return `0` on success (no error, tests *true*) or `1` otherwise. If you are testing with `if` it's simply `if script_or_utility; then echo "success"; else echo "something bad happened"; fi`. No need to wrap the execution of the code in `[..]` or `[[...]]`. You can also just check `$?` which holds the return of the last command run. (also, have fun experimenting with ANSI escapes for color -- then forget about them -- they are completely terminal dependent)

Comment: Thanks you for your answer, the program i want to check return `Server is running` when the server is running or `No server running (ts3server.pid is missing)` when is not running.

Comment: Why not just check `[ -e 'ts3server.pid' ]`? (or is that on the other box?) To test the string you would use `[...]`, e.g. `if [ $(command) = 'Server is running' ]; then echo "success"; else "it's bad"; fi`

Comment: It *outputs* `Server is running`; it does not return it.

Comment: You can just test for the `.pid` if you have passwordless access between the server and host, e.g. just run `ssh user@server "[ -e '/path/to/ts3server.pid' ]";` then test `if [ $? -eq '0' ]; then echo "success"; else "it's bad"; fi`

Comment: I finally found what I wanted to do, i'm sorry my english is bad and in consequence my explanation too. `if [[ $(bash "$TSFOLDER"/ts3server_startscript.sh status) == "Server is running" ]]; then` Thank you for your time.